# im trying to make a discord macro to send a message nonstop

Tags: automation, discord, autohotkey

I'm using https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm to create a discord macro to basically spam a message in one of my servers nonstop. I want to have ctrl+4 to activate it and I want ctrl+5 to stop it, I also want it to wait until the message is sent to send the next one. I keep getting errors and cant make it work, does anyone here know how I should do it?

Comment: its not that complicated because i only want the bot to spam 1 thing nonstop, im sorta new to this so i will take all the help i can get, also if you have a solution or code i can use to make it please post it here. im using autohotkey v2

Comment: So it has nothing to do with discord? Are you asking for an AutoHotKey macro? Also, this is not a code request forum. You will have to do some research yourself, [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=autohotkey+tutorial) is often a good resource. Once you have tried to do this, we can help you out. But not if you don't have anything done. Best of luck!

Comment: its a macro for discord. im asking for information on how to make it.

Comment: I am aware of that. But what you are requesting is most likely against [Discord ToS](https://discord.com/terms#:~:text=You%20agree%20that%20your%20use,at%20support%40discord.com.). Like I said, watch a tutorial and try solving it yourself first. We will not give full solutions without you making any effort.

Comment: it is for my own server therefor it is not against tos, ive looked for tutorials but dont understand how it works, my current code has a timer for 1 seccond after each message but after the timer i dont know how to make the messages send

Comment: Make it repeat: Paste (Ctrl+V), Enter, wait 1 second. Repeat?

Comment: yes sorta like that, i want it to loop the code until I press the button to stop it and wait like maybe 100 milliseconds

Comment: i cant find out how to make the program run ctrl+v

Answer (score 0):

Easier to just send what you have copied in your clipboard.

Make a new script file (ending with .ahk) and paste this in. You can toggle it on and off with F1.

```
#NoEnv 
SendMode Input  
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 3

F1::
Toggle := !Toggle
Loop, {
    If (!Toggle)
        Break
    Send %ClipBoard%
    Send {Enter}
    Sleep 1000
}
```

You can tweak this if need be.

***Make sure to use it only when you are allowed to.***